# Mahout K-means clustering gives me result like 0 belongs to cluster 1.0: []

Tags: machine-learning, mahout

I ran the K-means clustering algorithm against a set of sequence files. However, the generated result looks like this:

> 0 belongs to cluster 1.0: []
>
> 0 belongs to cluster 1.0: []
>
> 0 belongs to cluster 1.0: []
>
> 0 belongs to cluster 1.0: []
>
> 0 belongs to cluster 1.0: []
>
> 0 belongs to cluster 1.0: []

The program I use is borrowed from NewsKMeansClustering.java, an example given in chapter 9 of Mahout-in-Action.

Would you like to let me know why I get this type of result? Is that because of any specific parameter setting requirement or anything else?

The core clustering code in this program is

```
CanopyDriver.run(vectorsFolder, canopyCentroids, new EuclideanDistanceMeasure(), 250,    120, false, false);

KMeansDriver.run(conf, vectorsFolder, new Path(canopyCentroids, "clusters-0"), 
clusterOutput, new TanimotoDistanceMeasure(), 0.01, 20, true, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue using Mahout 0.5.
I think the problem is that the normPower parameter is used in both functions.
Try code similar to this.

```
DictionaryVectorizer.createTermFrequencyVectors(tokenizedPath,
                outputDir, conf, minSupport, maxNGramSize,
                minLLRValue,
                -1.0f, // no normalization here
                logNormalize, numReducers, chunkSize,
                sequentialAccessOutput, namedVector);
TFIDFConverter.processTfIdf(vectorOutput, new Path(outputDir,
                "tfidf"), conf, chunkSize, minDf, 
                maxDFPercent,normPower,
                logNormalize, sequentialAccessOutput, namedVector,
                numReducers);
```

After that I stopped having problems with empty clusters.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem.  As a newbie it was very difficult to solve.  However, in my case, I realised that the T1 and T2 values for the canopy clustering were only valid for the Reuters data (and Euclidean norm) provided.  I had used my own document data which seemed to have an inherently different distribution of distances between document vectors.  So I did some rudimentary analysis then re-estimated T1 and T2 from my own data.  Then things worked.  See my post also at...

[How to pick the the T1 and T2 threshold values for Canopy Clustering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224343/how-to-pick-the-the-t1-and-t2-threshold-values-for-canopy-clustering/8061756#8061756)

Hope this helps.